# Barcode Scanning issues

Tags: vb.net

After a long practice and consulting the internet I have been able to differentiate 
keyboard input from scanned input successfully.

I have 2 textboxes (txtScannedInput and txtKeyboardInput) and 
1 label (lblDisplayScannedInput) to display the scanned input.

Everything works perfectly when the txtScannedInput textbox has focus before 
a barcode is scanned.

My only problem is when the txtKeyboardInput has focus before 
a barcode is scanned the first 2 characters of the barcode stays in the txtKeyboardInput 
while the rest of the charcters move to the txtScannedInput.

(I know it is because my calculations to differentiate keyboard input from 
scanned input is based on keypress, so by the time it get to know that the input is a scanned 
one 2 of the characters have already been entered in the txtKeyboardInput and it moves to rest to the txtScannedInput.)

Can anyone help me to improve on my code or is there a better way of doing this?

```
Public Class frmFinalBarCode
Dim datLastTimePress As DateTime = Date.Now
Private Sub frmFinalBarCode_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If (DateTime.Now.Subtract(datLastTimePress).Milliseconds > 50) Then
        Me.Text = "This is a keyboard input"
    Else
        Me.Text = "This is a Scanner input"
        datLastTimePress = DateTime.Now ' Initialize the timer for the first character

        txtScannedInput.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmFinalBarCode_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    datLastTimePress = Date.Now
End Sub

Private Sub txtScannedInput_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtScannedInput.KeyPress
    lblDisplayScannedInput.ResetText()
    lblDisplayScannedInput.Text = txtScannedInput.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have to set e.Handled = True to suppress the keystroke in the wrong TextBox.  Do consider using only *one* TextBox so there is never any confusion about which control requires the focus.  That TextBox ought to always be usable to receive input both from the scanner and the keyboard.  Or get a better barcode scanner,  one that doesn't function like a keyboard wedge.

Comment: My suggestion is to enumerate the devices, and if the device is a keyboard, store the GUID associated with it or vendorID. It shouldn't be too difficult to tell one from the other, and create a class with keypress Raisevent that carries the GUID or vendorID of what keyboard the keypress originated from. This of course is not a complete solution to your problem. It's just a suggestion from where to start...

Comment: The form need both keyboard input and barcode input so 2 textboxes are needed @ Hans

Comment: They just don't need to exist on the same window since they are never used at the exact same time.  Make it crystal-clear to the operator and provide a "Barcode mode" window.  With only one textbox so it never goes wrong.  And an easy way to close it so your program operates in "Keyboard mode".